# Changes done to global js variables inside Geocoder function does not persist Outside the Function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I want to get Latitude and Longitude of a set of addresses.This is the code I used.

```
var marker_array = [];
//Event detail array
var LiveEventDetails= <?php echo json_encode($liveEventsDetails); ?>;

LiveEventDetails.forEach(function(event) {
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': event.venue }, function (results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
    marker_array.push([results[0].geometry.location.A,results[0].geometry.location.F]);
    }
    //1st test
    console.log(marker_array);
  });
  // 2nd test  
  console.log(marker_array);
});
//3rd test  
console.log(marker_array);
```

the output(marker_array) given by the first console.log() has the pushed data in it..
But after the geocoder function marker_array is shown as empty by the 2nd and third console.log();

How can I keep the pushed array after the geocoder function without being empty..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: It doesn't happen with other functions..happened with Geocoder function only

Comment: What other functions?  Are they asynchronous like the geocoder?

Comment: No In a Synchronous function..Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that the callback function used by the geocoder, which contains your "test 1", is asynchronous. This means that `marker_array` is being populated correctly, it is just empty or incomplete when "test 2" and "test 3" run. The true value of `marker_array` will be the last output from "test 1".

P.S. There is a limit to amount of geocoding uses ([source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)):

> The Google Maps API provides a geocoder class for geocoding and
>   reverse geocoding dynamically from user input. When you first load the
>   API, you will be allocated an initial quota of Geocoding requests.
>   Once you have used this quota, additional requests will be
>   rate-limited on a per-second basis. If instead you wish to geocode
>   static, known addresses, see the Geocoding web service documentation.